# Nested Active Directory Groups causes user unable to authenticate against application

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, directory, groups

User is placed in a global group called **site.gg1**

**site.gg1** is a member of a global group called **region.gg1**

**region1** has been added to the server local group, which is mapped to the application role. Application is called XHQ and is web based

Users are not able to authenticate. What could be the issue?

Comment: Google suggests XHQ doesn't support nested global groups, but what do I know, never had anything to do with XHQ myself.

Comment: Thanks. We do actually have servers that are hosting XHQ, and it's working. That's why it is a little baffling. All the servers are using the same OS and hardware.